# Error creating Roslyn SDK Template Project

Tags: c#, roslyn, vs-extensibility

Trying to create a Diagnostic with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX) project on the latest VS2015 CTP release.

After I try to create the project I get the following errors:

[image: Problem creating project]
[image: Problem creating test project]
[image: Problem creating .vsix project]

Any idea on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the project, make sure you set the .NET Framework version to 4.5, not 4.5.3.

(I've run into exactly this problem before, and setting the version to 4.5 fixed it. I believe this is a known issue, and I'd expect *at least* a better experience before shipping, e.g. stopping the process before it gets as far as creating project files.)